# Finding real roots of $f(x) = 4x^5 + x^3 + 7x - 2$

Tags: roots

$$f(x) = 4x^5 + x^3 + 7x - 2$$

$f'(x)>0$ for all $x$, But $f''(x)=80x^3+6x$ can be negative for negative $x$, so is the function strictly increasing?

Comment: This function has one real root on the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: Since $f^\prime$ has no zero in $\Bbb R$, By Rolle there has to be only one zero at max. Since $f$ has odd degree, therefore only one zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=x^2(20x^2+3)+7$ is positive,  thus function is definitely increasing. Getting a negative $f"(x)$ is nothing but getting a local maxima in increasing function
 and $f(0)=-2$ while $f(1)>0$. Thus this shows that this function has a real root in $(0,1)$ and this is **only** real root for $x>0$

Comment: So the second derivative does not make a difference in it being strictly increasing?

Comment: Nope. It does not

Comment: @onelessproblem The concavity of a function does not dictate wheather it's increasing or not. For example, $e^x$ is concave up and increasing. $\ln x$ is concave down and increasing.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you to notice that you can get a local maxima/minima only at critical points. which, over here is $x=0$ @onelessproblem

Comment: @BarryCipra Edited. Thank you.